# DataArray pass Data to MatTableDatasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I become an Array from API Service like this.

```html
0: {pkkopfTaetigkeitId: 1, erfDatum: "2020-03-07T00:00:00", taetigkeit: "Reifen wechseln",…}
pkkopfTaetigkeitId: 1
erfDatum: "2020-03-07T00:00:00"
taetigkeit: "Reifen wechseln"
ersatzteile: null
kmstand: 11000
reifen: true
bremsen: null
service: null
kranservice: null
fkkennzeichenId: 25
fkpersonId: 2
stunden: 0.75
uebergebenAm: null
kennzeichen: {pkkennzeichenId: 25, kennzeichen1: "GM-234A", kostenstelle: 46, gueltigVon: "2020-03-05T00:00:00",…}
pkkennzeichenId: 25
kennzeichen1: "GM-234A"
kostenstelle: 46
gueltigVon: "2020-03-05T00:00:00"
gueltigBis: "2099-12-31T00:00:00"
kopftaetigkeit: []
```

Now i pass the Data to the Datasource with this function

```
 this.erfassungService.getTaetigkeiten().subscribe(data1 => { this.dataSource.data = data1, this.loading = true }
```

that shows me the Date in the Table. But i need from the second row the Name from the kennzeichen1

> kennzeichen: {pkkennzeichenId: 25, kennzeichen1: "GM-234A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLOSED:
i have not export the other Objectarray from Person.